# Execute multiple async functions at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I want to execute multiple async functions at the same time, here is an example

```
import asyncio


async def sayhello():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("hello")


async def saybye():
    print("Bye")


async def execute():
    await sayhello()
    await saybye()

asyncio.run(execute())
```

Like, i want to execute "sayhello" and "saybye" at the same time, so first is gonna say bye, wait 5 seconds, and say hello, Not wait 5 seconds and say "hello, bye"

Comment: what if You put that sleep in the other function?

Comment: That's not the point, i want to figure out a way to do it by executing the functions at the same time. It's just a simple example for tell you my trouble.

Comment: `await asyncio.gather(sayhello(), saybye())`…

Comment: dude, python works line by line, if it sees that it has to sleep it does that and then moves on at least in Your case that seems to be the case tho I am don't have as much knowledge about this